# Use RegEx in Java to extract parameters in between parentheses

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm writing a utility to extract the names of header files from JSPs. I have no problem reading the JSPs line by line and finding the lines I need. I am having a problem extracting the specific text needed using regex. After looking at many similar questions I'm hitting a brick wall.

An example of the String I'll be matching from within is:

```
<jsp:include page="<%=Pages.getString(\"MY_HEADER\")%>" flush="true"></jsp:include>
```

All I need is MY_HEADER for this example. Any time I have this tag:

```
<%=Pages.getString
```

I need what comes between this:

```
<%=Pages.getString(\"  and this: )%>
```

Here is what I have currently (which is not working, I might add) :

```
String currentLine;
while ((currentLine = fileReader.readLine()) != null)
{
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<%=Pages\\.getString\\(\\\\\"([^\\\\]*)"); 
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(currentLine); 
while(matcher.find()) {
System.out.println(matcher.group(1).toString());                           
}}
```

I need to be able to use the Java RegEx API and regex to extract those header names.

Any help on this issue is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

EDIT:

Resolved this issue, thankfully. The tricky part was, after being given the right regex, it had to be taken into account that the String I was feeding to the regex was *always* going to have  two  " / "  characters ( (/"MY_HEADER"/) ) that needed to be escaped in the pattern.

Here is what worked (thanks to the help ;-)):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<%=Pages\\.getString\\(\\\\\"([^\\\\\"]*)");
```

Comment: Will the target text contain any back slashes ? Eg. instead of HEADER_FILE would it ever contain this character \ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
<%=Pages\\.getString\\(\\\\\"([^\\\\]*)
```

Yeah that's a scary number of back slashes. `matcher.group(1)` should return MY_HEADER. It starts at the `\"` and matches everything until the next `\` (which I assume here will be at `\")%>`.)

Of course, if your target text contains a backslash (`\`), this will not work. But you didn't give an indication that you'd ever be looking for something like `<%=Pages.getString(\"Fun!\Yay!\")%>` -- where this regex would only return `Fun!` and ignore the rest.

**EDIT**

The reason your test case was failing is because you were using this test string:

```
String currentLine = "<%=Pages.getString(\"MY_HEADER\")%>";
```

This is the equivalent of reading it in from a file and seeing:

```
<%=Pages.getString("MY_HEADER")%>
```

Note the lack of any `\`. You need to use this instead:

```
String sCurrentLine = "<%=Pages.getString(\\\"MY_HEADER\\\")%>";
```

Which is the equivalent of what you want.

This is test code that works:

```
String currentLine = "<%=Pages.getString(\\\"MY_HEADER\\\")%>"; 
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<%=Pages\\.getString\\(\\\\\"([^\\\\]*)"); 
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(currentLine); 
while(matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1).toString()); 
}
```

Comment: @lars_bx - You were using a bad test case in your code that you had posted previously in the comment. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @lars_bx -- It's written like (\"NAME_HERE") or (\"NAME_HERE\") ? Either way the best way is to write up a script that reads the file to string and then throw that at the regex.

Comment: @lars_bx Yes... Read the data from file into a String, pass that String to the Matcher, and watch the Console output. If you want to copy-paste test input by hand, you'll need to properly escape it first, like I demonstrated in the above code. So instead of `(\"NAME_HERE\")` you'd need to escape it to `(\\\"NAME_HERE\\\")`.

Comment: @lars_bx - it has to be something with your input. It compiles and runs fine with The sample input from before. If I were you I'd wrap it in a try-catch block inside the outer while-loop and if an exception is thrown, print the input line to screen.

Comment: @lars_bx if the \ aren't actually present, then try this regex: `"<%=Translations\\.getString\\(\"([^\"]*)"`